# 2-Dimensional Recursion

Tags: java, data-structures, recursion

I am implementing a 2-dimensional data structure for a class. My desired approach is an "NxN" Array of objects.

So,

```
    Cell[][] dataStructure = new Cell[N][N];
```

My current issue, is that I am very rusty with recursion. Each cell relies on the output of the cell to the left of it, and to the cell above it, to create its output.

[image: Example of 2-D structure and how the outputs flow into the next cells]

Example:

> Assuming standard X,Y directions, I would like to be able to call a
>   getOutputX method for a cell, Cell[X][Y], and it would recursively
>   call getOutputX for Cell[X-1][Y] and getOutputY for Cell[X][Y-1] until
>   it reaches the edge of the array. At this point, the outputs would
>   propogate back through the array and return the desired output for the
>   cell.

As I write this out I'm understanding more as I go along, and I feel like I'm very close. Any helpful input or hints would be appreciated.

My specific question is how to create a getOutput method that would get the required input from both the cell above, and the cell to the left of the desired output.

Comment: You can just do a nested loop. The value of (X-1,Y) and (X,Y-1) will be available when you process (X,Y)

Comment: Wow, I think I just hurt my brain ... but I like your comment nhadtdh, it soothes the brain a bit.

Comment: What are you trying to do? From looking at the image, it seems like you are trying to 'backtrack' from a given position and aggregate all the cells (across all paths) that converge towards it.

Observation: 

- A given cell will be 'entered' to from the cell to the left, or the cell above

- (and vice versa) the only 'navigable' cells from a given position is the immediate neighbour to the right, and the one below

Comment: You need to decide of three things: what's the output for a cell on the left edge (and which thus has no left neighbour), what's the output for a cell on the top edge (and which thus has no top neighbour), and given the output of the left and to neighbours of a cell, what's the output of the cell (i.e. how do you combine the neighbors outputs with the cell to get the cell's output. Once you have this defined, it's a matter of 10 lines of code.

Comment: @JB Nizet Cells on the top and left edges are hardcoded inputs, I will spare the details but they will be used to test every possibly binary combination of inputs. 

Given the requred outputs, they are then ran through two different logic gates. One logic gate for the x-direction, and one logic gate for the y-direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is quite simple:

```
int getOutput(x, y) {
    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
        return hardCodedInput(x, y);
    }
    int leftOutput = getOutput(x - 1, y);
    int topOutput = getOutput(x, y - 1);
    return logicGate(x, y).applyLogic(leftOutput, topOutput);
}
```

Comment: It seems that this is working, thanks again! Now if I can figure out what glitch I've managed to include that makes the answer come out wrong ^-^